# Fancy apt-get output

Tags: command-line, apt, colors

How can you have a cleaner and fancier output with or with out colors form apt-get not apt
something like the yum update output

Comment: aptitude is an advanced interface for apt, although I'm not sure if fulfills your demands. The output is pretty similar, but at least it has an ncurses-like GUI if you don't like it's shell commands.

Comment: I found a [blog post](http://www.kereoz.org/apt.html) that suggests writing your own wrapper for the `aptitude` (or `apt-get`) commands and using `grep` with the `color` option to highlight some keywords. It works for me, though the approach is certainly limited.